# Apache tomcat start up failure

Tags: netbeans

I have been working with netbeans...til yesterday night it worked but now i couldnt run even a simple code its showing the following comments in the output screen

```
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 8084 is already in use.
D:\Dhivya\Job\calculator\payodaproject\nbproject\build-impl.xml:683: Deployment error:
Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 8084 is already in use.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

how to recover from this

Comment: You need to free port 8084.

Answer (score 0):

First this isn't a constructive question as there is obvious lack of research. You didn't mention whether you tried to find out if any process was using port 8084. You may use netstat command to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when there is a Tomcat process already running and for whatever reason Netbeans is not able to see it, and tries to start another.  You have to kill the Tomcat process manually, then Netbeans will be able to start it again.

Answer (score 0):

It's a netbeans bug for port 8084 and there are few ways to resolve it. One is to remove *tcnative-1.dll* from the *apache-tomcat/bin* folder in your installation. For more you can visit [netbeans-bugzilla](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=191607#c2).